# Why didn't the Wakandans destroy the alien ships?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

The people of Wakanda have very advanced technology. So why didn't they destroy the alien ships that were attacking Wakanda in *Avengers: Infinity War*? Why did Thor have to do it?

Were the Wakandans unable to do so, or would it simply have been too difficult for them?

Comment: Wakandan technology is advanced by Earth standards but not by galactic standards

Comment: ....I think the better question is, "why did the Wakandans charge into melee, instead of using more machine guns?" (and mortars, and mines, and....)

Comment: Aliens have advanced technology too. ;)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Actually, their weapons can fire accurate and powerful energy missiles (so guns seem unnecessary). But they don't use them much. Alas, that's a superhero film failing. People want to see punching and slashing, not energy blasts.

Comment: Also keep in mind that vibranium is a magical metal, basically (sorry, "alien metal"). So stabbing with a vibranium weapon is still better against tough alien beasties than using any kind of conventional weaponry.

Comment: @Obie2.0 What about Vibrainium bullets? Although I agree with you, it is far more entertaining to see the heroes in close combat with the monsters rather than the realistic option of standing 100 metres away and blasting vibranium machinegun fire at them

Answer (score 24):

The likely reason for this is the energy barrier that surrounds Wakanda. Things can't enter the barrier (at least, not without sustaining severe physical trauma), but they also can't *exit* the barrier. This is demonstrated when one of Thanos' henchmen is propelled into the roof of the barrier by the Hulkbuster's arm, and the barrier slowly incinerates him until he explodes.

If the Wakandans wanted to fire upon the alien ships, they would have had two options:

1. Open a hole in the barrier, and fire through it. It seems they
   would have been reluctant to do this: when T'Challa orders a hole to
   be opened in the barrier to let the aliens through, the other
   Wakandans react as though he's gone mad.
2. Invent a weapon that could fire through the barrier. The film appears to indicate that they don't have such a weapon, otherwise they would have been firing at the aliens *before* they passed through the barrier.

Comment: i think they have jets wich can fire from ouside barrier without any human in it..They can handle it within barrier.like they destroy vibranium ships in blackpanther climax

Comment: Different barrier @Dfan - the one at the end of BP was not a defensive shield designed to hold enemies outside, it was just an illusion.  Ships could (and did) pass through it.  Even if it was that particular defensive barrier, in `Black Panther` Everett Ross was tasked with destroying the ships BEFORE they got past the illusion and to the outside world.

Comment: Then how he uses car in BP?

Comment: @Dfan To phrase things differently, by my recollection the barrier used to stop the aliens in Infinity War was not used at all in Black Panther. I don't know what car you are talking about, but the barrier shown in Infinity War is different.

Comment: @KamilDrakari And the original illusion barrier is shown earlier in Infinity War as well, when the quinjet flies through it.

Answer (score -1):

Advanced technology does not always mean advanced weaponry. And most likely, the ship of Thanos are protected.
In any case, the ships landed unexpectedly. And arms at least would not have had time to prepare.

Comment: Unexpectedly? Not sure I'd say that.